# OpenGL: why does glMapNamedBuffer() return GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Tags: opengl, runtime-error, buffer, memcpy

Using OpenGL 4.6, I have the following (abbreviated) code, in which I create a buffer and then attempt to map it in order to copy data over using `memcpy()`:

```
glCreateBuffers(buffers.size(), buffers.data()); // buffers is a std::array of GLuints
// ...
glNamedBufferStorage(buffers[3], n * sizeof(glm::vec4), nullptr, 0); // I also tried GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT
// ...
void* bfrptr = glMapNamedBuffer(buffers[3], GL_WRITE_ONLY);
```

This latter call returns GL_INVALID_OPERATION. I am sure that this is the call that generates the error, as I catch OpenGL errors right before it as well. The [manpage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBuffer.xhtml) suggests that this error is only generated if the given buffer handle is not the name of an existing buffer object, but I'm sure I created it. Is there anything else I'm missing or that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create [immutable buffer storage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object#Immutable_Storage), you *must* tell OpenGL how you intend to access that storage from the CPU. These are not "usage hints"; these are requirements, a contract between yourself and OpenGL which GL *will* hold you to.

You passed 0 for the access mask. That means that you told OpenGL (among other things) that you were *not* going to access it by mapping it. Which you then tried to do.

So it didn't let you.

If you want to map an immutable buffer, you *must* tell OpenGL at storage allocation time that you're going to do that. Specifically, if you want to map it for writing, you *must* use the `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` flag in the `gl(Named)BufferStorage` call.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that's what `GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT` was for, but I completely missed that the `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT` flag exists. Stupid of me!